# produce a ordered log while while using multiple processors

Tags: logging, makefile, multiprocessing

I am running a makefile which runs several executable files.
Since I am using -j flag ,the make commands executes these executable file in parallel fashion .Due to this the log on the stdout I am receiving is not ordered.
I want my makefile to run the executables in parallel fashion but I must receive the running status of those files in ordered manner i.e the log on the stdout must show the start and end status of a executable file consecutively for better understanding of which files have been started and ended.
Kindly help me how can I achieve this task.

Comment: Then you must define an order for them to run, so they won't run in parallel any more. See [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).

Comment: This the only problem.I want them to run in parallel but the console output should be ordered.That is the output should show which files have started running ,which have not started,which have ended something like a dynamic console.And all this has to be implemented in makefile